# Heroku - running a "ps" command via API

Tags: heroku

Is there a way to run command "heroku ps" via the Heroku API? I am interested in knowing how long a particular worker has been running.

For example I want to get this output: `urgent.1: up for 2h`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Heroku's RESTful JSON API](https://api-docs.heroku.com/ps#GET/apps/ps) or one of the many API wrapper libraries: [Ruby](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb), [Java](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.jar), [Python](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py).  There are also a few others created by the community.